# Poincare lemma: from local to global solutions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-analysis

I am reading a book by Moskowitz and Paliogiannis where I miss a point when trying to complete a proof of the Poincare lemma (which is left to the reader).

The following facts are proved clearly in the book.

**Fact 1:** Let $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a $C^{1}$-mapping (vector field), $\Omega$ an *open ball* in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and
$$
 \forall i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}\; \forall x\in\Omega: \quad \frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}(x)=\frac{\partial F_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}(x).
$$
Then $F$ is conservative, i.e., there is a $C^{1}$-funcion $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mbox{grad} f =F$.

**Fact 2:** Let $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a $C^{1}$-mapping, $\Omega$ a region (=open and connected) in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and for any closed $C^{1}$-curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$, it holds that
$$
\int_{\gamma}F\cdot ds=0.
$$
Then $F$ is conservative.

The goal is to prove the following:

**Theorem (Poincare lemma):** Fact 1 remains true if $\Omega$ is any simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

I miss a point when trying to pass from balls to simply connected domains. I suppose that one should elaborate on Fact 2 and use the simple connectedness of $\Omega$.

**Question:** How should I construct the potential $f$ on a simply connected domain $\Omega$ provided that I am aware of Facts 1 and 2?

Comment: "Simply connected" does not imply contractible.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: OK, I edited that.

Comment: Probably we can define $f$ locally, using Fact 1., and prove that these match by Fact 2.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that for homotopic $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ and curl-free $F$ one has $\int_{\gamma_0} F = \int_{\gamma_1} F$?  The proof of this statement is indeed to break the homotopy into small segments and apply Fact 1. Then use the fact that in a simply connected domain, any loop is homotopic to a point, over which the integral of any $F$ is zero. Then by your fact 2 the result follows.